# Script for showing/hiding on click - how can I write this code cleaner?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have this simple code, but its messy - how do i do it cleaner? It works like this: if you click on the menu-btn1 the div shows up, and hide others, but if you click on menu-btn1 again it will hide as well.

```js
let coll = document.getElementsByClassName('collection');
let dis = document.getElementsByClassName('display');
let drop = document.getElementsByClassName('drop');

document.getElementById("menu-btn1").addEventListener("click", function() {
  if(coll[0].style.display == 'none') {
    coll[0].style.display = 'block';
    dis[0].style.display = 'none';
    drop[0].style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    coll[0].style.display = 'none';
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="menu">
    <span id="text"><span id="menu-btn1">collection</span></span>
</div>

<div class="collection" style="display:none;"></div>
<div class="display" style="display:none;"></div>
<div class="drop style="display:none;"></div>
```

There is nothing important in css really, only the grid positioning.

Answer (score 0):

You could move the [0] to the variables instead of using it when setting the styling.

```
let collection = document.getElementsByClassName('collection')[0];
let display = document.getElementsByClassName('display')[0];
let drop = document.getElementsByClassName('drop')[0];
        
document.getElementById("menu-btn1").addEventListener("click", function() {
  if(collection.style.display == 'none') {
    collection.style.display = 'block';
    display.style.display = 'none';
    drop.style.display = 'none';
  } else {
     collection.style.display = 'none';
  }
});
```

Or you could create a function to hide and show elements.

```
let collection = document.getElementsByClassName('collection')[0];

function showElement(elementId) {
  return document.getElementsByClassName(element)[0].style.display = 'block';
}

function hideElement(elementId) {
  return document.getElementsByClassName(element)[0].style.display = 'none';
}

document.getElementById("menu-btn1").addEventListener("click", function() {
  if(collection.style.display == 'none') {
    showElement('collection');
    hideElement('display');
    hideElement('drop');
  } else {
    showElement('collection');
  }
});
```